# Colorbox and Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, colorbox

we have a wordpress site and we want to track whenever someone goes through the wordpress gallery on the said article. Right now we are using

```
<script>
  $("a[rel='gallery1']").colorbox({onComplete:function()
  {_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $(this).attr('href')]);}}); 
</script>
```

and it works fine but only for the initial opening it seems. Any ideas how to track the "Next" and "Previous" hits? We have contacted the developer of Colorbox but wanted to post it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

That should work for the 'Next' and 'Previous' hits.  I'm not sure what the situation is with using relative URLs when manually tracking pageviews.  I assume it's not a problem, but it may be better to use `this.href` rather than `$(this).attr('href')`, as that would give the absolute URL rather than the exact value of the href property.  For example:

```
<a href='../../pic1.jpg'>1</a>
<script>
    // for http://example.com/dir1/dir2/page.html
    $('a').attr('href'); // returns '../../pic1.jpg'
    $('a')[0].href; // returns 'http://example.com/pic1.jpg'
</script>
```